# How to check utilization of fixed thread pool

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I'm running a Java application that uses a fixed thread pool, where threads are used to make HTTP requests to external services.

The thread pool was purposefully overprovisioned, and I want to obtain some measurements for utilization of the thread pool (i.e, at this moment, 20% of the threads in the pool were free, at this other moment 30% of threads were busy).

Is there an efficient way of checking what proportion of the thread pool (created through the Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x)) is currently performing a task?

I had thought about creating a special monitor thread that continually runs a Callable task, reporting back the utilization, but I wasn't certain if that would impact performance of the tread pool itself (by making threads respond to the monitor instead of making HTTP calls).

Comment: Use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly; it provides various "debug" methods.

Answer (score 6):

**ExecutorService#newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)** returns an instance of ExecutorService, but if you look at the source code, you see that they basically create a new instance of **ThreadPoolExecutor** and cast it to ExecutorService.

So you could just do this:

```java
final int poolSize = 15; // your thread pool size
final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
```

On this ThreadPoolExecutor instance, you can use one of the many methods you can find in the Javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#method.summary

Just to name a few that you might find useful: 
 - [ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount()) 
- [ThreadPoolExecutor#getTaskCount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getTaskCount()) 
- [ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getPoolSize())